# Java Web Framework similar with Ruby on Rails paradigm

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, frameworks, jakarta-ee

in your opinion, what is java web framework that most close to or similar to the paradigm of the Ruby on Rails (like convention over configuration, DRY, noXML, etc), but without the need to learn scripting languages ​​like Groovy. And of course have a great documentation and community.

Comment: Grails?  what did Google say? And why no scripting language? Groovy is close enough to Java to have a shallow learning curve for many things.

Comment: grails is written in groovy. Is that Java?

Comment: hmm i've no experience in Groovy, but after see some screencast and try a little bit about groovy feature like assertion, is look like promising, thx 4 your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look to [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) it follow MVC and RESTful architectures.

Comment: yes after see introduction screencast, its similiar with Rails, but is there any book about play framework. i didn't found nothing in amazon

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) which follows the paradigms of Ruby on Rails.

Comment: http://www.ubertracks.com/preso/#/intro Will explain why Grails is superior over play framework

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but have looked at Spring Roo?

Comment: Not a good answer either! What's Spring Roo? Care to elaborate more :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but this information may still be useful for people looking for a good java framework:
Try ninja framework (http://www.ninjaframework.org). I have tried various java web frameworks and this one was by far the easiest to setup and use. Just follow the tutorial on their page.

Developing with it is very easy, ninja web projects are standard Maven projects so you can open them with any ide that supports Maven. For example, you can open the project with Netbeans, and have the development server running in a commandprompt/terminal window. Any time you save your changes the development server will pickup your changes and restart very quickly. 
Or you can use a standard text editor if you want.

Very comfortable to develop with. You can also debug very easily from Netbeans (http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/debugging.html)

Note: if you use an ide like netbeans, you dont actually run the project from netbeans, you just edit your changes on the ide and save. The development server picks up the changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) is what you are after.

http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at Java on Rails

http://www.javaonrails.net/